# Trying to select a record set from aMongoDB collection filtering on a boolean field

Tags: c#, mongodb, boolean, filtering

I am very new to MongoDB and am trying to select data from a collection and filter the selected set by a boolean flag. The issue I am experiencing is that no records are selected. The code is written in C# and uses the MongoDB.Driver, .Bson and Driver.Core libraries

I've read forums and blogs and tried so many things but nothing seems to get the expected result. If anyone can shed any light or suggest a better way of achieving this I would be exceptionally grateful. The code is presented here:

```
    public async Task ProcessFirstTimeBillers()
    {
        var userProfiles = _db.GetCollection<UserProfiles>("UserProfiles");

        var builder = Builders<UserProfiles>.Filter;
        var filter = builder.Eq(x => x.FirstBillRequestSent, false);

        using (var cursor = userProfiles.Find(filter.ToBsonDocument()).ToCursor())
        {
            while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)
                {
                    var jsonDoc = doc.ToJson();
                    var s = jsonDoc.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea about c#, but what happens if you try the same query in mongo shell?

Comment: The problem is that the MongoDB C# libraries wrap a query in an Entity type thing.

From the command line I can do something like :
 db.UserProfiles.find({"Created":{$lt:ISODate("2017-05-10")}}).pretty()

Which does pretty much what I want, albeit without a cursor (maybe Mongo implements the find using a cursor but it's hidden from me)

Comment: This is the equivalent from the Mongo command line:
db.UserProfiles.find(
    {
        "Created":
        {
            $lt:ISODate("2017-05-10")
        }
    })

Comment: But I thought you're querying a boolean field?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
userProfiles.Find(filter.ToBsonDocument())
```

write

```
userProfiles.Find(filter)
```

and it should work.

The `ToBsonDocument()` is a generic extension method that will take any object and transform it into some Bson structure taking into account all the class mappings and serialization settings. It is **not** overwritten by the FilterDefinition type and will produce some funky filter like in your case

```
{ "_t" : "SimpleFilterDefinition`2" }
```

which effectively instructs MongoDB to search for any document that has a "_t" field with string value of "SimpleFilterDefinition`2" which I presume you don't have in your database --> so you get no results.

**EDIT:**

Here is a complete example that works.

```
public class UserProfiles
{
    public ObjectId Id;
    public bool FirstBillRequestSent;
}

public class Program
{
    public static IMongoDatabase _db;

    public static async Task ProcessFirstTimeBillers()
    {
        var userProfiles = _db.GetCollection<UserProfiles>("UserProfiles");

        var builder = Builders<UserProfiles>.Filter;
        var filter = builder.Eq(x => x.FirstBillRequestSent, false);

        using (var cursor = userProfiles.Find(filter).ToCursor())
        {
            while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)
                {
                    var jsonDoc = doc.ToJson();
                    var s = jsonDoc.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                    // prints something like:
                    // { "_id" : ObjectId("5944439d82d2e7265c86d50c"), "FirstBillRequestSent" : false }
                    // { "_id" : ObjectId("5944439d82d2e7265c86d50d"), "FirstBillRequestSent" : false }
                    // { "_id" : ObjectId("5944442b82d2e718d827d5d6"), "FirstBillRequestSent" : false }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
        _db = client.GetDatabase("test");

        var collection = _db.GetCollection<UserProfiles>("UserProfiles");

        collection.InsertOne(new UserProfiles { FirstBillRequestSent = true });
        collection.InsertOne(new UserProfiles { FirstBillRequestSent = true });
        collection.InsertOne(new UserProfiles { FirstBillRequestSent = true });
        collection.InsertOne(new UserProfiles { FirstBillRequestSent = false });
        collection.InsertOne(new UserProfiles { FirstBillRequestSent = false });
        collection.InsertOne(new UserProfiles { FirstBillRequestSent = false });
        ProcessFirstTimeBillers().Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the repy dnickless. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: I added a complete example which you should be able to simply copy+paste+run. It certainly works on my machine...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for all your replies. They helped me imensely and have led to me getting expected results.

However, since I have put the code in a Windows service that runs the query in a Timer interval event, no rows are returned in spite of the same code running as expected when run outside of the service.

Does anyone know of any deficiency in MongoDB that prevents it running within a Windows timer event within a service?

Comment: That must be caused by a typo or something in the collection name or so... The driver will definitely work in an identical fashion no matter what process it's being run from. If you like my answer above and it solved your problem feel free to mark it as accepted. Thanks!